# How to list all objects in OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

Not sure how to phrase that question, but basically, I have an object constructor:

```
function myObject(name, type, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size; 
}
```

Then I create all of the objects (could be in the hundreds if I continue this pet project)

```
var newObject1 = new myObject("test name", "test type", "test size");
var newObject2 = new myObject("foo name", "foo type", "foo size");
var newObject3 = new myObject("bar name", "bar type", "bar size");
//etc.
```

Now, is there a loop that allows me to iterate through each object that comes from the `myObject` constructor?  I tried using this:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject));
```

but of course I don't know how to iterate through each object.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, the runtime provides no such facility. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @pointy, I would like to be able to list all of the objects in a select box or manipulate them some other way possibly.  I'd like to show them on the screen

Comment: You really should just put them in an array.

Comment: @bergi, You're saying manually?  That shouldn't be a problem, though if there are updates to the piece I'm doing this for, I will have to cross check each.  I don't necessarily want to play all of the properties as well as the object name in an array, I just want the object name.  So I assume, as you said, manually making an array should work just fine.

Comment: @ntgCleaner: By "manually" I just meant that adding to the array should not happen implicitly. `var newObjects = [new myObject(…), new myObject(…), new myObject(…)];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javascript runtime does not provide any facility to iterate all objects of a particular type.  If you really need to do this, then you will have to keep track of all such objects in some sort of data structure (probably an array).

In fact, if you're creating hundreds of objects all with uniquely named variables, then that's a red flag right there that you probably should be writing your code to use an array of those objects and access them by array index rather than each by uniquely named variable.  This will also make your code a lot more compact.

---

Though it is sometimes frowned upon in Javascript (because it defeats garbage collection for individual instances until they are removed from the array), you can also make the object just keep track of it's own list of objects by having the constructor just add each newly created object to a list.

```
function myObject(name, type, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size; 
    myObject.list.push(this);
}

myObject.list = [];

// to iterate all myObject instances
for (var i = 0; i < myObject.list.length; i++) {
    // myObject.list[i]
}
```

Note: you could also maintain the ability to create an object that was not put in the list, but just creating a factory function that create the object and puts it in the list:

```
function myObject(name, type, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size; 
}

var listOfMyObject = [];

function makeMyObject(name, type, size) {
    var o = new myObject(name, type,size);
    listOfMyObject.push(o);
    return o;
}

// to iterate all myObject instances
for (var i = 0; i < listOfMyObject.length; i++) {
    // listOfMyObject[i]
}
```

Comment: In the OPs use case, he should use an array as well but fill it manually (not through the constructor)

Comment: My scenario is complicated and by reading your statement "then that's a red flag" I'm wondering if I'm doing this the right way. But I think that's a different question all together.  Thank you for the answer,  I will try this and if it gets too sloppy/heavy, I will make a manual array to house everything as @Bergi says.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't think we know enough about what the OP is actually doing to know if the array should be built automatically or manually.  If there is no other use for this object where the object should not be in the array, then I see no issue with writing code to automatically put it in the array.  One does need to be aware of the impact on garbage collection if the array isn't being actively maintained.  For completeness, I added another alternative with a factory function that puts it in the array while the regular constructor does not.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to each object then print that collection.

```
var myObjects = [];
function myObject(name, type, size) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.size = size;
  myObjects.push(this);
}

// A bunch of new myObject()...

console.log(myObjects);
```

Comment: The design might be better to have the `push` action happen outside of the constructor, when the objects are being created. Either that or make the array a static property of the `myObject` constructor. As it is now, the location of the list and the responsibility of maintaining it are split between inside and outside of the constructor.

Comment: True but placing it inside of the constructor ensures that every reference is collected. It's just a matter of how you want to organize your code and if you want to repeatedly type `myObjects.push`.

Comment: If you want to ensure that every instance is captured, why not make sure that the location of that capturing (the array) is bundled with the object constructor? That makes it more portable, if nothing else.

Comment: That definitely works. I agree with your second idea about making the array a static property of `myObject`, I was just refuting your first point.

Comment: I was just giving two different design paths for completeness' sake. I definitely also think that the second one (keeping the list on `myObject`) is the better option.